# Image is not visible (source is not recognized)

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm making a simple web-app in React.js (+ Spring in back).

**I have problem with displaying a photo (.img) from local path in function *displayItems*. Picture is not visible. If i load file from web in the same code (src="http.......") everything is fine.**

Could you help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../index.css';

class Author extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        mail: window.location.href.slice(32, -7),
        items: 2,
        loadingState: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.iScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        if (this.refs.iScroll.scrollTop + this.refs.iScroll.clientHeight >=this.refs.iScroll.scrollHeight){
            this.loadMoreItems();
        }
    });

}

displayItems() {
    var items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.items; i++) {
        //PROBLEM
        items.push(<img src="../resources/Photos/1.jpg"></img>);
    }
    return items;
}

loadMoreItems() {
    this.setState({ loadingState: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ items: this.state.items + 2, loadingState: false });
    }, 3000);
}

render() {
    return (
          <div
              className="vc"
              ref="iScroll"
              style={{ height: "200px", overflow: "auto" }}
          >
              <h2>My adventures: </h2>
              <div>
                  {this.displayItems()}
              </div>
              {this.state.loadingState
              ? <p className="loading">
              loading More Images..
              </p>
              : ""}
          </div>
    );
}
}
export default Author;
```

Comment: Your general approach looks fine. Can you look in your browser's debugger and see what the HTML for the img tag is when it's on the page? Here's a demo example working: https://codesandbox.io/s/5yrvrvl7lx

Comment: I believe the problem is the location of your images. You're using them with a relative path without `import`ing or `require`ing them. Then the compiler does not know it should add them to root bundle. You can try moving then to your public folder.

Comment: thx, you are wright. DO you know why: const image = require("../resources/Photos/1.jpg"), but const image = require("../resources/Photos/" + i + ".jpg); doesnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to get the image using require or import and then use it in the src,

```
const image = require("../resources/Photos/1.jpg")

...

items.push(<img src={image}></img>);
```

Comment: thx, you are wright. DO you know why: const image = require("../resources/Photos/1.jpg"), but const image = require("../resources/Photos/" + i + ".jpg); doesnt?

Comment: Most probably because `i` doesnt have a value if you have placed the statement before initializing `i`