# reactstrap carousel html tag on variable

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

good day to all. im new to react app, and i usses reactstrap for my carousel. i just copied the code from reactstrap documentation. and i want to add a html tag on the item variable. but just print the html tags on my website. how do i do it correctly?

my variable is:

```
const items = [
  {
    imageUrl: 'static/media/slide1.jpg',
    idName: 'S1',
    captionHeader: 'slide 1 <strong>text here</strong>',
    captionText: 'slide 1 <strong>text here</strong>',
  },
  {
    imageUrl: 'static/media/slide2.jpg',
    idName: 'S2',
    captionHeader: 'Slide 2',
    captionText: 'Slide 2'
  }
];
```

then i added it here:

```
<CarouselItem
          onExiting={this.onExiting}
          onExited={this.onExited}
          key={item.src}
        >
          <div className="carouselIMG" id={item.idName} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.imageUrl})` }}>
            &nbsp;
          </div>
          <CarouselCaption captionText={item.captionText} captionHeader={item.captionHeader} />
        </CarouselItem>
```

this part:

```
<CarouselCaption captionText={item.captionText} captionHeader={item.captionHeader} />
```

p.s.
can you aso check my "imageUrl" is there a best way to grab the image location? atfirst i tried ../images/imagename.jpg, just like what i do when im importing js file. but it doesnt seem to located the address, so i just manually check if where the images are stored when build.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that in react strap documentation the prop types are,

```
CarouselCaption.propTypes = {
  captionHeader: PropTypes.string,
  captionText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  cssModule: PropTypes.object
};
```

So the `captionHeader` and `captionText` need to be strings. How ever you can give `font-weight` css style for this whole text.

And regarding the picking of images you may check out this [SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50653847/1971908).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting the values rendered in the user view, but what you want is the values stored on a tag on the html.

Note that CarouselCaption is not html, it is a custom react component. ;)

You need to place the following code like attributes on native html tags to get them stored in html dom.

`<div> captionText={item.captionText} captionHeader={item.captionHeader}> </div>`

A good example is found in their github repo under demos.

https://github.com/gajus/react-carousel/blob/master/demo/src/index.js

Here you notice that they create an array of a bunch of these using map.

```
<div key={String(index)}>{index}</div>;
```

Then they render this as a child of the carousel. So you'd just put your attributes on the html. With html I can create a div like

```
<div thisIsACustomHTMLAnAttribute="valuesToBeStoredInTheDom"> </div>
```

However the equivalent in custom react component would try to either pass to the component for use or try to render it as values.

```
<div captionText={item.captionText}> </div>
```